# scanning multiple pages with scanimage

Tags: hp, scanner

I wish to scan multiple pages with my HP ENVY scanner, it does not have a page feeder.  I don't mind where the files are created or what name and type they are, I'll convert them to a single pdf file after scanning.
Have tried:-

```
scanimage --batch  --batch-prompt  --resolution 150
```

And various other permutations but get `scanimage: sane_start: Invalid argument` all the time.

Any advice would be welcome

Comment: Have you tried `gscan2pdf` or the default `Document Scanner` (simple scan as was)? I use both on 18.04 and 20.04 with an HP colorlaserjet printer.

Comment: I'm actually calling scanimage from a programme so I'm not sure your suggestions would work.

Comment: With the default `Document Scanner` it loaded it's own driver in the background which had to be selected otherwise it would error. Give it a try. No harm done otherwise.

Comment: I should have said that I'm calling scanimage from the command line.  This way my programme controls the scan parameters.  Am looking at both simple-scan (nice) and gsca2pdf.  Thanks

Comment: gscan2pdf allows you to reorder the pages quite neatly.